# How to find: $\lim\limits _{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{3} \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos (2 n x)}{1+x^{8}} d x$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-transform

**Problem:**
What is the following limit?
$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{3} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos (2 n x)}{1+x^{8}} d x$

**Attempt:**
Denote $ f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^8} $ for $ x \in [ -\pi , \pi] $ ( Note that this function is infinitely differentiable. )

$ I_n = n^{3} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos (2 n x)}{1+x^{8}} d x = \frac{n^{3}}{2} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{ e^{2inx} + e^{-2inx} }{1+x^{8}} d x =  \frac{2\pi \cdot n^{3}}{2} ( \hat{f}(2n) + \hat{f}(-2n) ) $.
Now we use  $ \hat{f^{(k)}}(n) = (in)^{k}f(n) $ ( since $ f$ is indeed differentiable on its interval ), thus
$ I_n = \frac{2\pi \cdot n^{3}}{2} ( \hat{f}(2n) + \hat{f}(-2n) ) = \pi \cdot n^3 ( \frac{\hat{f^{(3)}}(2n)}{-2^3n^3} 
 + \frac{\hat{f^{(3)}}(-2n)}{-2^3n^3} ) = \frac{-\pi}{8} ( \hat{f^{(3)}}(2n) + \hat{f^{(3)}}(-2n)  )   $
And by Riemann-Lebesgue we get $ I_n \to 0  $.

I'm not really sure whether the limit I calculated is justified or the proof's specious ( Which, I think it is but I don't know why, probably where I said that $ \hat{f^{(k)}}(n) = (in)^{k}f(n) $ ). then I had doubts whether the limit is $ 0, \infty, -\infty $ or none of them, I think it's none of them but don't have a gist of justification as to why. Can you please help as to how to find the limit? thanks very much for the help in advance!

Comment: Since the integrand is an even function of $x$, you may simplify the limits of the integral when you start the solution!

Comment: An elementary way is to integrate by parts two or three times.

Comment: @Gribouillis that means $ \int u v' = uv - \int u' v  $ . If we take $ u = \frac{1}{1+x^8} $ then we'll get $ u' = \frac{-8x^7}{(1+x^8)^2} $ and then continue somehow integration by parts with that with that. If however we take $ v' =\frac{1}{1+x^8}  $ then we'd have to do an integral of it.  In either case it seems we proceed to a much more difficult problem than we initially thought and I don't see how we integrate by parts less than 4 times

Comment: Do it with $u = \frac{1}{1+x^8}$ and $v' = n^3 \cos(2 n x)$, but you need to take the bounds $\pm\pi$ into account, then do it a  second time and see what you obtain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Too long for a comment*

Using the recommendation of @Gribouillis, integrating by part several times, using the fact that the integrand is even and denoting $\,\Big[\frac{1}{1+x^8}\Big]^{(k)}=\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\frac{1}{1+x^8}$
$$I(n)=2\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos (2 n x)}{1+x^{8}} d x=\frac{1}{n}\frac{\sin 2nx}{1+x^8}\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=\pi}+\frac{1}{n}\int_0^\pi \sin (2 n x)\Big[\frac{1}{1+x^8}\Big]^{(1)}d x$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2n^2}\cos (2 n x)\Big[\frac{1}{1+x^8}\Big]^{(1)}\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=\pi}+\frac{1}{2n^2}\int_0^\pi \cos (2 n x)\Big[\frac{1}{1+x^8}\Big]^{(2)}d x$$
$$=-\frac{4}{n^2}\frac{\pi^7}{(1+\pi^8)^2}+\frac{1}{4n^3}\sin (2 n x)\Big[\frac{1}{1+x^8}\Big]^{(2)}\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=\pi}-\frac{1}{4n^3}\int_0^\pi \sin (2 n x)\Big[\frac{1}{1+x^8}\Big]^{(3)}d x$$
$$=-\frac{4}{n^2}\frac{\pi^7}{(1+\pi^8)^2}+\frac{1}{8n^4}\cos (2 n x)\Big[\frac{1}{1+x^8}\Big]^{(3)}\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=\pi}-\frac{1}{8n^4}\int_0^\pi \cos (2 n x)\Big[\frac{1}{1+x^8}\Big]^{(4)}d x$$
Evaluating the third term:
$$\frac{1}{8n^4}\bigg|\int_0^\pi \cos (2 n x)\Big[\frac{1}{1+x^8}\Big]^{(4)}d x\bigg|<\frac{1}{8n^4}\bigg|\int_0^\pi \Big[\frac{1}{1+x^8}\Big]^{(4)}d x\bigg|<\frac{\operatorname{Const}}{8n^4}$$
Therefore,
$$I(n)=-\frac{4}{n^2}\frac{\pi^7}{(1+\pi^8)^2}+O\Big(\frac{1}{n^4}\Big)$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^3I(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(-n\frac{4\pi^7}{(1+\pi^8)^2}\Big)=-\infty$$
Numeric check at WolframAlpha confirms the result. At $n=10 \,000$
$$10^{12}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{\cos(20\,000\, x)}{1+x^8}dx=-1.341589316...$$
while
$$-\frac{4\pi^7}{(1+\pi^8)^2}\cdot 10\,000=-1.341589346...$$

Comment: You’re often on this site with nice contour integration. It seems to me that, where $\gamma$ is the unit circle, the integral is: $$\Im\oint_{\gamma}\frac{z^{2n-1}}{1-i\cdot\ln^8(z)}\,\mathrm{d}z$$And I believe that there are no poles here (the denominator is $0$ when $\ln(z)=\exp\left(i\left(-\frac{\pi}{16}+n\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)$ which has no roots in the unit disc) and the essential singularity at $z=0$ is ok because we are “dividing by infinity” and it evaluates to $0$, right? But then Cauchy’s integral theorem would say the integral is $0$, which is false... what is wrong?

Comment: @FShrike Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, logarithm has a branch point at $z=0$, so we have to make a cut (from example, $[0;\infty)$ ) which we are not allowed to cross (to keep the integrand a single-valued function). But I will think whether we can use the complex integration to get the asymptotics.

Comment: +1, Can you suggest some completely beginner contour integration books?

Comment: I studied complex analysis many years ago. Regarding modern books, I discovered for myself MATHEMATICAL METHODS FOR PHYSICISTS by George B. Arfken. The part about complex integration is comprehensive, detailed and contains a lot of interesting problems

Comment: @4444 Sorry, did not use your nickname. My suggestion about the book is in the comment above

Comment: @Svyatoslav thanks :)

Comment: @FShrike, I posted some investigation of how complex integration can be used to find the asymptotics.

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer - just the investigation of the idea whether the method of complex integration can be used to find the solution (a questions in one the comments).*

In my opinion, complex integration is not an adequate method to find the asymptotics of this integral. However, it can be used to rewrite the integral in more convenient form.

Let's consider a more general case:
$$\boxed{\,\,I(n)=I(n,a,b)=\int_{-a}^b \frac{\cos (2 n x)}{1+x^8} d x\,\,}$$
where $a,b>0$ - some constants. Making the substitution $t=\frac{x}{n}$
$$I(n)=n^7\int_{-an}^{bn} \frac{\cos (2 t)}{n^8+t^8} d t=n^7\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos (2 t)}{n^8+t^8} d t-n^7\int_{-\infty}^{-an} \frac{\cos (2 t)}{n^8+t^8} d t-n^7\int_{bn}^\infty \frac{\cos (2 t)}{n^8+t^8} d t$$
$$=n^7\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos (2 t)}{n^8+t^8} d t-n^7\int_{an}^\infty \frac{\cos (2 t)}{n^8+t^8} d t-n^7\int_{bn}^\infty \frac{\cos (2 t)}{n^8+t^8} d t\qquad(1)$$
The first integral can be evaluated via complex integration. As usual, adding a big half-circle of the radius $R$, we get a closed contour. Integral along this half-circle $\to 0$ as $R\to\infty$.
$$n^7\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos (2 t)}{n^8+t^8} d t=Re \,n^7\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{2 iz}}{n^8+z^8} dz=n^7 \Re \,2\pi i \sum\operatorname{Res}\frac{e^{2 iz}}{n^8+z^8}$$
The integrand has poles at $z_k=n\,e^{\frac{\pi i}{8}+\frac{\pi i k}{4}}, \, k=0,1,2 ... 7$, and we have to take only $z_k$ from the upper half-plane (where our contour lies), and where $\Im\, z_k>0$.
Therefore, all the residues contain the factor $\sim n^7\frac{e^{-\beta n}}{n^7}\sim e^{-\beta n}, \beta>0$ and are exponentially small at $n\to\infty$.
It means that with the accuracy up to exponentially small corrections, we can consider only two last terms in $(1)$. Making the inverse substitution $t=nx$
$$I(n)\sim -\int_{a}^\infty \frac{\cos (2 nx)}{1+x^8} d x-\int_{b}^\infty \frac{\cos (2 nt)}{1+x^8} d x\qquad(2)$$
The asymptotics can be easily found via integration by part (please, note that $a,b>0$ - the arbitrary constants, so we do not impose any special requirement to the boundaries).
$$I(n)\sim -\frac{1}{2n}\frac{\sin (2 nx)}{1+x^8}\bigg|_a^\infty -\frac{1}{2n}\frac{\sin (2 nx)}{1+x^8}\bigg|_b^\infty$$
$$+\frac{1}{2n}\int_{a}^\infty \sin (2 nx)\Big(\frac{1}{1+x^8}\Big)^{(1)} d x+\frac{1}{2n}\int_{b}^\infty \sin (2 nx)\Big(\frac{1}{1+x^8}\Big)^{(1)} d x$$
$$I(n)\sim -\frac{1}{2n}\frac{\sin (2 na)}{1+a^8}-\frac{1}{2n}\frac{\sin (2 nb)}{1+b^8}+\frac{\cos (2 na)}{(2n)^2}\Big(\frac{1}{1+a^8}\Big)^{(1)}+\frac{\cos (2 na)}{(2n)^2}\Big(\frac{1}{1+b^8}\Big)^{(1)}+...$$
Where $\big(\frac{1}{1+x^8}\big)^{(k)}=\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\frac{1}{1+x^8}$.

Integrating as many times as we want, we get the asymptotics as the series of powers $\frac{1}{2n}$.

Comment: Nice: thanks for the notification